# Do Something on WPF Form Minimize –PowerShell (version 5)

Tags: wpf, forms, powershell

I have PowerShell script that creates a WPF form from inserted XML code. This form will run on a kiosk station and has no window (so no maximize, minimize, or close buttons) and consumes the entire screen.

Even though the form itself has no window buttons, a person can still press the <kbd>WIN</kbd> key on a keyboard, get the task bar, right click on the form in the task bar and choose to minimize, maximize, or close for the form.

So, I set an action for close to lock the workstation (which is better option for this kiosk instead of preventing the form from closing at all) by doing this:

```
$form.Add_Closing({
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
    $shell.Run("%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation")
})
```

I would also like to do this for Minimize if possible, but can’t seem to figure out how.

FYI. I’m not intending this to be a *security* feature per-se, but more so something that is better done then not for this kiosk station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$form` is your form, then you could try this (wrapping the repetitive part in a function to stay DRY):

```
function Lock-Workstation {
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
    $shell.Run("%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation")    
}

$form.Add_Closing({ Lock-Workstation })

$form.Add_StateChanged({
    if($form.WindowState -eq "Minimized") {
        Lock-Workstation
    }
})
```

Since you don't want the window to be resized anyway, you could simply use:

```
$form.Add_StateChanged({ Lock-Workstation })
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try using Add_Resize I get an error:


"Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Window] does not contain a method named 'Add_Resize'."

Comment: `Resize` is for `WinForms`, sorry. It seems `StateChanged` works with `WPF` ^^. I have edited my answer.